# Flex referring to Image from the SWC file

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How do I reference an image in Flex that has been included in the SWC file?

Answer (score -1):

Use the `Embed` metadata tag. Something like:

```
source="@Embed(source='relativeOrAbsolutePath')"
```

The syntax for embedding resources is given [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_3.html):

> The syntax that you use for embedding assets depends on where in your application you >embed the asset. Flex supports the following syntaxes:

```
* [Embed(parameter1, paramater2, ...)] metadata tag

  You use this syntax to embed an asset in an ActionScript file, or in an <mx:Script> block in an MXML file. For more information, see Using the [Embed] metadata tag.
* @Embed(parameter1, paramater2, ...) directive

  You use this syntax in an MXML tag definition to embed an asset. For more information, see Using the @Embed() directive in MXML.
* Embed(parameter1, paramater2, ...) directive

  You use this syntax in an <mx:Style> block in an MXML file to embed an asset. For more information, see Embedding assets in style sheets.
```

All three varieties of the embed syntax let you access the same assets; the only difference is where you use them in your application.

Read the [section](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=projects_5.html) on loading resources from the documentation. Also, [Embedded Asset Classes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=04_OO_Programming_09.html).